# Use jQuery to add class to first item inside every foreach loop

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, foreach

This code returns an array and then uses a foreach loop to output each item. I want to add a class called 'active' to the first .item class on every foreach loop that is run.

The jQuery I included at the bottom does add a class of active, but only to the first instance of .item on the **page**.  I would like it added to the first .item on every pass of the loop.

I am trying to dynamically create a bootstrap carousel

```
   <div id="carousel-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">

         <?php 
         $screenshots = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'screenshots', false);

         foreach ( $screenshots as $screenshot ) { ?>

            <!-- Slide items -->
            <div class="item">
               <img src="<?php echo $screenshot; ?>">
            </div>

         <?php }?>

      </div>

   </div>




<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery( '.carousel-inner .item:first' ).addClass( 'active' );
});
</script>
```

Comment: show html and js in a jsfiddle and what is the expexcted output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

numerous ways to do it, here's one using `find()`

```
jQuery( '.carousel-inner').find('.item:first' ).addClass( 'active' );
```

Will look within each instance of `carousel-inner` for first item

Answer (score 1):

I'm some sort of divided on your question, but let me see if i got right... I've understood two different things, i will present the solution for both:

**Maybe you want to hightlight the first one on each row on client:**

If yes, you could do something like this:

```
// Example on every 3rd it founds
jQuery( '.carousel-inner .item:nth-child(n/3)' ).addClass( 'active' );
```

or **maybe you want to do that on server (i would prefer that!)**:

```
<?php foreach ( $screenshots as $i => $screenshot ) { ?>

    <!-- Slide items -->
    <div class="item <?= is_int( $i / 3 ) && 'active' || '' ?>">
       <img src="<?= $screenshot; ?>">
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

Hit me up if you have any further question. :)